# How does coverage calculate its percentages?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have this result from running coverage, and I can't for the life of me figure out how the coverage percentages are calculated..?

[image]

In this [example](https://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0.3/branch.html#branch-coverage-measurement) it explains branch coverage, but doesn't say anything about coverage percentages for the example.

**update:** here are the details for pfind.py:
[image]

Comment: [*"It monitors your program, noting which parts of the code have been executed, then analyzes the source to identify code that could have been executed but was not."*](https://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0.3/) It's the percentage of potentially-executable code which is executed during tests, generally measured per-line.

Comment: @JeremyBanks yes, I understand what code coverage is/does, but the percentages doesn't seem to have any relation to the number of lines covered or the branch count..?

Comment: I think you need to see the missing branches in order to re-calculate the percentages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`coverage` is counting each branch as two possible instructions and giving them the same weight as non-branching instructions. Using this formula:

[image: (run+partial)/(statements+branches)]

Looking at `results.py` from the code, the coverage percentage is calculated in [`pc_covered`](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/results.py#L212), with the data obtained from [`ratio_covered`](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/results.py#L248) function:

```
@property
def ratio_covered(self):
    """Return a numerator and denominator for the coverage ratio."""
    numerator = self.n_executed + self.n_executed_branches
    denominator = self.n_statements + self.n_branches
    return numerator, denominator
```

As you can see, if branch coverage is enabled each branch will be accounted twice, once as a statement and once as a branch.